# What was wrong with my edit?

Tags: discussion, edits, suggested-edits

https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18399790

I thought I explained it clearly enough in the edit comment. The *only* problem the asker has is he's missing the @ in a decorator, so I'm struggling very hard to wrap my head around how editing the @ back in (hence [a] invalidating the accepted answer, [b] rendering the original question nonsensical because there is no longer anything wrong with it, and [c] potentially confusing future inquirers who may have the same problem and not realize the issue is theirs, not Flask's) is at all a constructive or logical contribution — and I further fail to see how, given the above parenthetical's premises, reverting the question to its original state could be considered by two different people (!!) to be "actively harm[ful]" to the question's readability or accessibility. Is there any etiquette or logic I'm currently missing?

Comment: This actually went wrong over two years ago with [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7522218).  Mistakes compounding mistakes, review is the site's worst feature.

Comment: yeah, I feel like Edit peer review doesn't work as intended generally.....  seems like too often they ignoring the actual change and do I don't know what -  maybe just vote on who has higher rep.  If I make a minor edit such as add one line to a code example that everyone is asking for in comments, half the time it's fine and half the time it gets rejected with reasons that make no sense like "this is a message to the author" --   clearly not about the content of the edit.

Comment: For what it's worth, I just looked at your edit and my first thought was that you were just adding spaces at the end of the returns. Upon closer inspection, I saw there was more to it than that, but I'm guessing those two reviewers didn't make it to the "closer inspection" step.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

What was wrong with that *review*, is that the reviewers haven't been paying attention.

I've rolled back the edit you tried to undo.

If you see this again, it may help to specifically say you're **rolling back** a **previous edit**, using those words. Ideally, that should trigger reviewers to check the edit history.

Comment: I see now, thank you lots! I'll keep this in mind, and will generally try to be descriptive regarding the 'what' of an edit alongside the 'why'.

Comment: @M.I.Wright, all that being said, you should probably reserve your edits for posts that are not closed or closable. A typo question is generally not worth bothering about.

Comment: @yivi Ah, thank you. That makes sense as well.

Comment: As the original question is deleted, I have to read the edit's comment again and again in order to understand what's wrong... Maybe the edits related to a deleted question should be also deleted.

Comment: @Sraw why? It's not like it's harmful to keep it. (And BTW you can see the full question by clicking on "rendered output")

Comment: @Veve Thanks, I didn't know that before.